# Selenium/Python2.7 Find elements with similar src?

Tags: python, css, selenium, src, element

```
from selenium import webdriver


fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
driver.get('')


list_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img[title]')
for ele in list_of_elements:
    print ele
```

I'm trying to print out all the img src=' ' of images on a webpage, the above code is for css selector and works well but I would like to do the same thing but have the code print out the src links of the images. Basically what im trying to do is make a list of all elements on the webpage based on the src= and then I can search through the src= and find the one I want. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are interested in `get_attribute()`:

```
srcs = [ele.get_attribute("src") for ele in list_of_elements]
```

Note that, since you are going to filter out elements based on `src` later - depending on how complicated the check would be, you may solve it by a single CSS selector. For instance, let's say you want to locate `img` element having the `title` attribute and "test" inside the `src` attribute:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img[title][src*=test]')
```

Here `*=` means "contains".